# mgtwitterengine get friends/ids and followers/ids

Tags: mgtwitterengine, twitter-follow

how to get users who not following me back in twitter by useing mgtwitterengine ?
how to get followers/ids and friends/ids

Answer (score 1):

For Friends ID's Use : https://api.twitter.com/1/friends/ids.json?cursor=-1&screen_name=ImpressolTest&include_entities=true

For Follower ID's use : https://api.twitter.com/1/followers.json?cursor=-1&screen_name=ImpressolTest&include_entities=true

After getting this values in array just check the friends array with followers array, you can get the users how are not following you back